# Difference between NPM and NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I know **npm** is the package manager and **nvm** is the node version manager. I am currently trying to auto-install my development and production environment using Bash and forgot how I started out and in what order. After installing npm, I found our nvm was not installed.

Do I still need to install nvm? If so, what is the benefit?

Comment: nvm installs Node which installs npm. If you don't need/want to switch between Node versions then you don't probably don't need nvm.

Answer (score 162):

[`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Node Version Manager) is a tool that allows you to download and install Node.js. Check if you have it installed via `nvm --version`.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash
```

[`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com) (Node Package Manager) is a tool that allows you to install javascript packages. Check if you have it installed via `npm --version`.

`npm` comes with Node.js so if you have node installed (`node --version`) you most likely have `npm` installed as well.

You don't need `nvm` unless you want to keep multiple versions of Node.js installed on your system or if you'd like to upgrade your version.

Comment: which means that i can use `nvm install watchman` instead of `npm install watchman` because i  don't want to change npm versions

Comment: @JokerFan That's not exactly true. You can not run `nvm install watchman`.  When you change your version of `node` with `nvm` the version of `npm` changes as well.

Comment: Does it makes sense to have multiple version of Node.js on system ?

Comment: @AjayS You may work on two separate projects that have very specific node version requirements, very common for contractors.

Answer (score 34):

nvm as you said is an "active" nodejs version manager. You can have multiple versions of node on the same machine and switch by doing "nvm use version". npm respects nvm if it is present on the machine, meaning if you have 0.12.7 active and do npm install -g uuid, it will install it globally under 0.12.7 but if you switch to 4.0.0, uuid will no longer be globally available.

In any case you do not necessarily need nvm to install packages.

Comment: which version comes with nvm please by default?

Comment: @JohnTheBeloved: None. nvm points to your OS' version by default.

Comment: @FelixKling is right. You can do "nvm ls" to see versions used by nvm and also "node -v" to see the currently active node.

Answer (score 17):

I see an analogy with Python for all the Python users out there.

`nvm` manages different versions of `node`. And `node` contains `npm` (package manager).

`pyenv` manages different versions of `python`. And `python` contains `pip` (package manager).