# How can I update Node version outside of usr/local/bin/ directory?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, miniconda

I am having issue getting my active Node version updated. How can I update Node version outside of `usr/local/bin/` directory? Subsequently, is `/Users/<>/miniconda3/bin/` an improper location to have Node located?

```
installed : v12.16.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v6.13.1 at /Users/<me>/miniconda3/bin/node
```

Comment: I think [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) can be your friend ^^

Comment: I see.. nvm is version manager and npm is  package manager https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660993/difference-between-npm-and-nvm

Comment: @moonwave99, thanks for the direction. Got it figure out.